# JSON-RPC service post request with response with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-post, json-rpc

I have a probleme. I will call JSON-RPC request. My Http post request on service.ts

service.ts

```
@Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class Service {
        
        public encoder: HttpParameterCodec;
        public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) {}
      
      
      public createBriefing(
      briefingData: Briefing //: Observable<any>
      ) {
      const url = "";
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      
      let body= new JsonRpcBody();
      body.id = briefingData.id;
      body.method = "query";
      body.params = briefingData.params;  
      
      this.httpClient.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
       }
      }
 export class JsonRpcBody {
          id:string;   
          method: string; 
          params: BriefingParameters[]
      }
      
      export class BriefingParameters {
      id: string;
      name: string[]
      city: string[]
      state: string[]
      }
```

component.ts

```
Brifing: any = { 
    id: 'query01',
    method: 'query',
    "params": [
      {
        "id": "briefing01", 
        "name": ["FIRST", "LAST"],        
        "city":["LONDON", "ARSENAL"],
        "state": ["ENGLAND"]
      }, 
    ],
    
  };
postBriefing(){
      this.service.createBriefing(this.Brifing)
    };
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="guestForm" >
    <table class="form-group" >     
        <tr>
            <th> Query: </th>
            <td ><input type="checkbox" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="Brifing.name"  class="form-control" id="" formControlName="" > FIRST
            <input type="checkbox"  formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="Brifing.name" class="form-control" id="" formControlName="" > LAST
        </td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
            <th> City</th>
          
            <td ><input type="textarea" formControlName="city" [(ngModel)]="Brifing.city"  class="form-control" id="" formControlName=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> State</th>
            <td ><input type="textarea" formControlName="state" [(ngModel)]="Brifing.state" class="form-control" id="" formControlName=""></td></tr>
   
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="postBriefing()">Create Briefing</button>
    <pre></pre>
    </form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> </th>
        <td> 3 rows </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

I want to sleep the data as
type, location, name in table.

The data is already displayed on the console, but if I write the name, adress,city in the table, the data does not appear.
what am I doing wrong?